# How to play media player with non-file and non-rtsp source?

Tags: android, media-player, rtsp, mpeg

We've a mpeg4 source that we would like to play in the media player. Our source is not in a file or on an rtsp server. It is hand coded to generate mpeg4 source on the fly. Imagine the data is coming from an unix pipe stream instead of rtsp or a file. How can I use that stream in media player?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not presently support streaming video other than through HTTP and RTSP, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I just wanted to find out if through NDK we've any access to Media Player or if we can extend the existing Media player work. Has anyone tried any such things? Any insight into what kind of issues could pop up?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot extend MediaPlayer through the NDK. For audio, you can use the NDK and AudioTrack to stream arbitrary stuff (e.g., SIP). However, I am not aware of a video equivalent to AudioTrack.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `MediaPlayer.setDataSource( FileDescriptor fd )` with the pipe.
Or with the combination of both `LocalSocket` and `LocalServerSocket`.